# Simulate Page Right and Page Left

Tags: keyboard

is there any way to simulate a "Page Left/Right" functionality?
With <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> (or <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> or any of the other various ways) I can scroll most Mac windows up or down "a page". However the behavior for left and right is very inconsistent or not present. I really would like to do the same for left and right directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Safari and other web views option-left (⌥←) scrolls a page left and option-right (⌥→) scrolls a page right, but it doesn't work in Chrome.

You can use [DefaultKeyBinding.dict](http://osxnotes.net/keybindings.html) or [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/xml.html.en) to make some key combinations move in different directions multiple times:

```
{
  "~p" = (moveUp:, moveUp:, moveUp:, moveUp:, moveUp:, moveUp:, moveUp:, moveUp:);
  "~n" = (moveDown:, moveDown:, moveDown:, moveDown:, moveDown:, moveDown:, moveDown:, moveDown:);
  "~b" = (moveLeft:, moveLeft:, moveLeft:, moveLeft:, moveLeft:, moveLeft:, moveLeft:, moveLeft:);
  "~f" = (moveRight:, moveRight:, moveRight:, moveRight:, moveRight:, moveRight:, moveRight:, moveRight:);
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>custom</name>
    <identifier>custom</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::P, ModifierFlag::FN, KeyCode::CURSOR_UP, KeyCode::CURSOR_UP, KeyCode::CURSOR_UP, KeyCode::CURSOR_UP, KeyCode::CURSOR_UP, KeyCode::CURSOR_UP, KeyCode::CURSOR_UP, KeyCode::CURSOR_UP</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::N, ModifierFlag::FN, KeyCode::CURSOR_DOWN, KeyCode::CURSOR_DOWN, KeyCode::CURSOR_DOWN, KeyCode::CURSOR_DOWN, KeyCode::CURSOR_DOWN, KeyCode::CURSOR_DOWN, KeyCode::CURSOR_DOWN, KeyCode::CURSOR_DOWN</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::B, ModifierFlag::FN, KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT, KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT, KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT, KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT, KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT, KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT, KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT, KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F, ModifierFlag::FN, KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

DefaultKeyBinding.dict doesn't work in some applications like Chrome or Xcode and Karabiner has a (barely) noticeable delay.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sad that there is no way wich works in every program :/